# How can I get the directory in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

I want to get the full path and the file name.
I tried

```
package looks;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "CSV files", "csv");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("directory and file : " +
                                chooser.getSelectedFile().getName() + 
                                chooser.getAbsolutePath().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to get the String like this `C:\\Users..\\Test\\myfile.csv` so that I could use it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "CSV files", "csv");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```